# Ordering in a query gives "call to an undefined function"

Tags: 8, database

I am using Drupal 8 and I am trying to order my query like so:

```
 $query = db_query("SELECT * FROM `heritage_source_info`WHERE text_id = :textid AND format = :format ORDER BY type ASC", [':textid' => $textid, ':format' => 'text'])->orderBy('FIELD(type,moolam,translation,commentary)');

$available_sources_text = $query->fetchAll();
```

But it says call to an undefined function orderBy(). Could you help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: look at the documentation for DB API: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned from [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_query/8.9.x) is an instance of a class implementing [`StatementInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21StatementInterface.php/interface/StatementInterface/8.9.x), which doesn't have any `orderBy()` method. Since you are using a SQL string, you can order the result adding an `ORDER BY` clause.

As side note, instead of `db_query()`, which is deprecated and it's going to be removed from Drupal 9, the code should use `\Drupal::database()->query()`.

The alternative is using `\Drupal::database()->select()`. In this case, the object returned, which implements [`SelectInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21SelectInterface.php/interface/SelectInterface/8.9.x), has a [`orderBy()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21SelectInterface.php/function/SelectInterface%3A%3AorderBy/8.9.x) method.